# How can you send a web request from inside an Android app?

Tags: java, android, http, get

Please excuse my lack of knowledge on the topic, but I have very little, if any knowledge of networking, PHP, web requests, and such. Essentially, I want to send a string to a website for logging using [$_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) variables. How can I send a string using this method, from inside the app?

(I can't self answer for another 6 hours, but if I COULD, here is what it would look like, with the code in the answer of course. Just didn't wan't to take away from the original question.)

In the end, the code [found here](http://pastebin.com/gG8M8rDi) worked.
The app sends a request to the web server, which then appends the string in the $_GET variable to a log file! Took a few hours to figure out though. :l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library to make HTTP requests.

HTTP request URIs consist of a protocol scheme, host name, optional port, resource path, optional query, and optional fragment.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
     "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=");
```

Query string can also be generated from individual parameters:

```
List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "httpclient"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btnG", "Google Search"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aq", "f"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oq", null));
URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "www.google.com", -1, "/search", 
    URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

Comment: But how do I get the app to actually send the request to the site USING that link?

Comment: You execute it with an implementation of HttpClient, for example: `new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpget);` see [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 0):

wanstein is right, but the *URIUtils.createURI* is deprecated now (4.2.1), so it is better to use the URIBuilder:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
                .setFragment("http")
                .setHost(HOST)
                .setPath(path)
                .setQuery(URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"))
                .build();
```

Comment: Isn't `http` the uri's fragment but its scheme?